# Javascript how to turn array detected as string to array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a list detected as a string like this one:

```
var list = "['one', 'two', 'three']"
```

Is there a way to turn this into an array:

```
var real_list = ['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Edit:
But I can't change the quotation marks of var list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try Using**

```js
var list = "['one', 'two', 'three']";
list = list.split(",");
list[0] = list[0].substring(1);
list[list.length - 1] = list[list.length - 1].substring(
  0,
  list[list.length - 1].length - 1
);
list.forEach((x, i) => {
  list[i] = list[i].includes('"') ? list[i].replaceAll('"', "").trim()
     : list[i].replaceAll("'", "").trim();
});

console.log(list);
```